# What do I ask for Allah for forgiveness by eating haram seafood without knowing it was haram?

Tags: halal-haram, food, forgiveness

Salam, I am Muslim but, unfortunately my parents haven't taught me much about our religion and I keep learning new information on my own and trying to tell them.

I went on vacation with my siblings and I have never heard that certain fish was haram in all my life apart from frogs.

I ate mussels in a pasta dish which I would never eat but did unfortunately to find out months later its haram to consume. I was never told crab and lobster is haram too.

I usually do not eat meat so I have more a pescetarian diet as I do not enjoy chicken or lamb or beef too much. of course since I was a baby I knew pork, frogs were haram.

I was totally in shocked to find this out and cannot believe no one has corrected me in all theses years. Will Allah forgive me for genuinely not knowing this was haram and what should I do to repent the sin.

Comment: Also please note that there is disagreement on whether some of the seafood you have mentioned is halal or haram.

Comment: who told mussels and lobster are haram? it's widely known in the arab world that they're halal and even very known scholars eats them.

Comment: The majority view is that seafood halal and there should be a question asking something similar on the site.